# Copy the values of primary key in new added column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this table named `Person` with column name `ID` which is a primary key. How should I copy the values from that column name ID in my new added table with column name `ID2`?
This is just a sample `ID` and `ID2`.

ID (1)  Values (Sample 1)  ==> Inside the parenthesis is value of that column

Now I addedd new table with column ID2 and Values2

ID2 (null) Values2 (null)

ID and Values here are `null` since there are no entry with the user.
What if I want to enter a value in Values2?
How should I code it so that Values2 will automatically have an ID equivalent to ID in table 1? Is it automatically added if I put a Foreign key contraint to ID2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe way is to determine the nature of the relationship between the two tables. Is it 1 to 1, 0..1 to 1, 0..1 to many. When you have set up the relationship correctly, then you can determine the best way to populate the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this sample:

```
UPDATE Person SET ID2=ID WHERE ID2 IS NULL
```